# How to create a new .pfx file from a old .pfx?

Tags: ssl, iis, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

Our exchange and many web servers SSl certs are going to expire.I have bought the renewal cert from godaddy.I got the .crt ,.pem and .p7b files but how do i change it to the .pfx?

I tried to export the old ssl cert from one of the iis server.It says a private key is combined with it.How to create a new .pfx file from a old .pfx?

Answer (score 0):

- After downloading the P7B (or CER) , double-click on the certificate file and the Windows certmgr application will open.
- You can find the install certificate option, Select that
- Install the certificate in your local machine
- After completing all the installation step you can see the certificate in your certificate manager right click on it and export
- Select export with a private key
- Select pfx format to export

[image]

Comment: so can i use the new exported .pfx to import all servers?It is because the ssl cert i bought is a wildcard cert.

Comment: @kinKin yes you can use that exported certificate on another server but make sure you exported the certificate with private key

Comment: so next year i just download the cert from godaddy then install it to the server.Then export the cert with private key as .pfx format.After that i can deploy it to any same domain servers right?